# How to parse nested JSON, within a string, using Kusto

Tags: json, azure, logging, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a Python Azure Function that produces custom logging messages when the Function executes. I need to pull out some of the JSON values nested in the logging message.

**How can I use Kusto to access the *nested* JSON within the logging message string?**

Example logging message:

- Desired values marked with `<----------`

```
####### EventGrid trigger processing an event: 
    {
        "id": "long-guid", 
        "data": {
            "api": "FlushWithClose", 
            "requestId": "long-guid", 
            "eTag": "long-guid", 
            "contentType": "application/octet-stream", 
            "contentLength": 16264, <----------------------
            "contentOffset": 0, 
            "blobType": "BlockBlob", 
            "blobUrl": "https://function.blob.core.windows.net/parentdir/childdir/file.name", 
            "url": "https://function.dfs.core.windows.net/parentdir/childdir/file.name", <---- JUST FILE.NAME here
            "sequencer": "long-guid", 
            "identity": "long-guid", 
            "storageDiagnostics": {
                "batchId": "long-guid"
            }
    }, 
    "topic": "/subscriptions/long-guid/resourceGroups/resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/accountName", 
    "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/containerName/blobs/childDir/file.name",
    "event_type": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
} #######
```

I imagine it has something to do with the Kusto `extend` function, but piping in...

```
| extend parsedMessage = todynamic(message)
| project timestamp, test = parsedMessage["id"]
```

...yields only an empty `test` column

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` in your specific case isn't a valid JSON payload - as it has the `###... EventGrid trigger processing an event:`  prefix (and a somewhat similar suffix).

- That is why `todynamic()` isn't able to process it and why you're not able to reference properties in the JSON payload that's included in it.

Ideally, you would change the payload you ingest to be a valid JSON payload, and re-type the target column to `dynamic` instead of `string`.

If you can't do that, you can use the `substring()` function or `parse` operator to get everything but the aforementioned prefix/suffix, and parse the output of *that* using `todynamic()`

- though note that doing that each time you query the data bears runtime overhead that could be avoided by following the advice above.

Comment: Thank you! Figured this out using `trim()` and `substring()`: `| extend parsedMessage = todynamic(trim(@"#######",substring(message, 46)))`

Comment: Once the `extended` function was applied, I used `| project operation_Id, timestamp, eventId = parsedMessage["id"], sourceContainer = split(parsedMessage["data"]["blobUrl"], "/")[3], fileName = split(parsedMessage["data"]["blobUrl"], "/")[6], contentLength = parsedMessage["data"]["contentLength"]` to access various pieces of the nested JSON shown in OP. Hope this helps others.