# Combine Complex Kusto Queries

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a Python Azure Function that produces custom logging messages when the Function executes. I'm able to pull specific info from the JSON inside the log strings ([thank you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117799/how-to-parse-nested-json-within-a-string-using-kusto/67118041#67118041) @yoni).

**How do I correctly combine 2 or more Kusto queries which parse different `logging` messages into a single query?**

**Example:**

- Each Azure Function execution produces several Python `logging()` messages (prepended with `#######`)
- I'm able to use Kusto to parse the needed info highlighted in yellow
  [image]
  [image]

**Kusto query** (spacing for readability):

```
let varLookback = ago(1d);

let varPath = 

union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > varLookback
| where message contains "####### Will write to"

//Pulls filePath out of Python logging string
| extend parsedMessage = todynamic(trim(@"#######",substring(message, 21)))
| project operation_Id, timestamp, filePath = parsedMessage;

union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > varLookback
| where message contains "####### EventGrid trigger processing an event"

//Pulls message JSON out of Python logging string
| extend parsedMessage = todynamic(trim(@"#######",substring(message, 46)))

//Parses fileName and contentLength from message JSON
| project operation_Id, timestamp, fileName = split(parsedMessage["data"]["blobUrl"], "/")[6], contentLength = parsedMessage["data"]["contentLength"]

//I've tried different join kinds here (inner, inner_unique, right_outer, etc. same erroneous results)
| join varPath on $left.operation_Id == $right.operation_Id
| order by timestamp asc
```

**Issue:**

- The combined Kusto queries shown above do not return the correct number of results.
- The results count should be 36 files, only 23 are returned
- I can't immediately see where the problem is (new to Kusto)

**EDIT 1:**

- After some troubleshooting, there seems to be a core discrepancy between the number of Function executions and the number of Function executions that contain the custom `logging` message.
- Verified count of Function executions in last 1d: **36**
- (this Function moves files between two storage accounts. I verified that 36 files were moved in last 1d)
  [image]
- Count of Function execution `logging` messages with keyword: **23**
  [image]

**Why are some Function executions not showing custom `logging`?**

Answer (score 3):

a. Make sure you've chosen the right `join` kind (default is `innerunique`([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)))

- If that doesn't help, perhaps including the (obfuscated) contents of both `join` legs in your question would help (as the total number of records seem low enough to fit)

Unrelated, perf tips:

1. Prefer using `has` over `contains` whenever possible ([doc](https://aka.ms/kusto.stringterms))
2. `trim()` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimfunction)) takes a regular expression as its first argument. Based on the content of your `message`s, see if you can choose a better operator function, that doesn't require a regular expression (e.g. `parse` operator or `substring()` function)

Comment: Added **EDIT 1:** above... complex topic!